# LINQ Order by - Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, linq, parallel.foreach

I have a very strange problem with LINQ "order by" and `Parallel.Foreach`

Specifically, this code works:

```
IList<IEntitaAssociabile> result = new List<IEntitaAssociabile>();

foreach(PraticheAperteNonAssegnate pratica in praticheAperteNonAssegnate)
{
    result.Add(new EntitaAssociabile
    {
          Id = pratica.ID_Prat,
          TipologiaEntita = TipologiaEntita.Pratica,
          DataApertura = pratica.DataAper.Value,
          TipologiaPratica = pratica.Cod_TpPrat,
          NomeCliente = pratica.Nominativo,
          NumeroPraticheDaAssociare = null,
          TipologiaEntitaPadre = GetEntitaPadre(pratica, praticheLotti, praticheSottolotti),
          IdEntitaPadre = GetIdEntitaPadre(pratica, praticheLotti, praticheSottolotti)
    });
}

return result.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

If I simply change `foreach` statement with `Parallel.Foreach`:

```
 IList<IEntitaAssociabile> result = new List<IEntitaAssociabile>();

 Parallel.ForEach(praticheAperteNonAssegnate, (pratica) =>
 {
      result.Add(new EntitaAssociabile
      {
           Id = pratica.ID_Prat,
           TipologiaEntita = TipologiaEntita.Pratica,
           DataApertura = pratica.DataAper.Value,
           TipologiaPratica = pratica.Cod_TpPrat,
           NomeCliente = pratica.Nominativo,
           NumeroPraticheDaAssociare = null,
           TipologiaEntitaPadre = GetEntitaPadre(pratica, praticheLotti, praticheSottolotti),
           IdEntitaPadre = GetIdEntitaPadre(pratica, praticheLotti, praticheSottolotti)
      });
  });

  return result.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

On the "order by" I have a "Null object reference exception"

I can't understand why with `foreach` the code works but not with `Parallel.Foreach`.

Can you help me and explain what's the problem?

Comment: Please write code in English.

Comment: Well, have a look at the `StackTrace` and once you know the line that actually throws the NRE try to fix it.

Comment: I want to say that a Parallel foreach for this usecase is not useful.

Comment: try with  lock (locker)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `List<T>` is *not thread safe*, that's why adding to `result` within `Parallel.ForEach` leads to problems. If you insist on parallel execution, try *PLinq* (*Parallel* Linq) instead:

```
IList<IEntitaAssociabile> result = praticheAperteNonAssegnate
  .AsParallel()
  .Select(pratica => new EntitaAssociabile() {
     Id = pratica.ID_Prat,
     ...
   })
  .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
  .ToList();
```

Comment out `.AsParallel()` if you want to switch to good old Linq.